# What is the source for the idea that only two mitzvot have a specific reward associated with them?

Tags: shiluach-haken, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, reward-punishment, sources-mekorot

I have heard it said that only the mitzvot of *kibbud av v'eim* (honoring parents) and *shiluach haken* (sending away the mother bird before taking eggs) are given with an explicit reward (that your days may be lengthened). Often times this is cited in relation to the story of Acher in the Gemara, although it doesn't seem to be there.

In fact, I can't find a source for it anywhere. And it would seem that Devarim 25:15 would be a third case (specifying honest weights and measures), so it would also seem to be wrong. Yet it also seems to be something that "everyone" knows.

Can anyone help track down a written source for the popular belief?

Answer (score 12):

It is easy to falsify the assertion that those are the only two *mitzvos* whose reward is stated. In fact, there is an entire category of *mitzvos* discussed in the *g'mara*, for which "*matan s'charah b'tzidah*" - "its payoff is [written] next to it". One ramification of being included in this group is that one cannot be coerced by the courts to perform those *mitzvos* (because there is enough incentive built into the command, according to some).

Hypothetical explanation for the source of misconception: Those two *mitzvos* in particular are associated strongly with each other and with this designation because they are the focus of a *g'mara* ([*Kidushin* 39b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=39b&format=pdf)) whose point is that material reward for any and all *mitzvos* may be (or is) actually immaterial in this world and only collectible in the next. As a result these *mitzvos* are commonly used as paradigms of this type of *mitzva* when discussing the ramifications of the type. For example, see the detailed analysis of the *S'de Chemed* on the topic [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ScM-AAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA47&ots=PTv5VA3B7y&dq=%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%94&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

The source is the Gemara in Kedushin 39b and Chulin 142a. דתניא רבי יעקב אומר אין לך כל מצוה ומצוה שכתובה בתורה שמתן שכרה בצדה שאין תחיית המתים תלויה בה בכיבוד אב ואם כתיב (דברים ה) למען יאריכון ימיך ולמען ייטב לך בשילוח הקן כתיב (דברים כב) למען ייטב לך והארכת ימים

Comment: These passages say that when torah gives the reward with the mitzvah it means after resurrection.  Neither says that these are the only two cases of that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, but it's easy to read that way.

Comment: @msh210: true.  I'm wondering if people who think there are just two are mis-reading this or if there is another source for that idea.

Comment: @MonicaCiello, yeah: see [WAF's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7292).

Answer (score 1):

The source of the story with Elisha Ben Abuya is Ruth Rabbah Parsha 6 #4 (on the paseuk 3:13). It's brought in shortened form in Tosafot Hagigah 15a.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=386Wom4lHGwC&lpg=PP1&dq=9781583302996&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false) (from sefer Shaleiach Tishalach p. 91) for an interesting essay on this topic.